# why does underscore defer fix so many of my issues?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

After using backbone for a couple of weeks I have realized that underscore defer ended up fixing many of the async issues I ran into regarding rendering various views. 
Can someone please help me understand exactly what underscore defer does and how is it different that $.ready() or other type of wait for dom to render functions. What are the down sides of using it ?

```
_.defer = function(func) {
    return _.delay.apply(_, [func, 1].concat(slice.call(arguments, 1)));
};
```

Comment: Well, what does `_.delay` do? Therein lies the answer.

Comment: it seems to wait for 1 millisecond. I still don't understand how that knows that certain elements are rendered etc. maybe I am using it incorrectly?

Comment: It may be more helpful if you post an example of a place you had to use `defer` and don't understand why.

Comment: This got to be my one of my favourite questions on SO. 'Sheesh this solves all my problem but I don't have a clue' :D

Comment: I've noticed that `_.defer` can cause memory leaks in my Backbone app. So while it may fix rendering issues, it can add memory ones.

Replacing `_.defer(_.bind(this.renderViews, this));` with `this.renderViews();` halved the amount heap profiles grew with navigation in my single page application. I think it is because it adds the possibility of screwing up the dereferencing of resources for when views close by doing work outside of the natural order. This obviously depends on how you use Backbone in the first place of course.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
# These are equivalent
_.defer(fn);
setTimeout(fn, 1);
```

So `defer` is simply a one millisecond `setTimeout`. *(It's got a few more convenience features but those aren't important here.)*

---

JavaScript has run loops.  It's single threaded, but its execution starts and stops based on events or timers.  Each time your JS engine kicks on to run some code, it's starting one iteration of its run loop.

So what `defer` does is say "run this code in the next run loop".

```
_.defer(function() { alert('after'); });
alert('before');
```

This alerts "before" and then "after".  This is because the the current run loop concludes which alerts "before", and then right afterward a new run loop starts and runs the code the alerts "after".

So anytime you have code right here, but you want it to run code which occurs after this code first, then you would use `defer`.

```
_.defer(functionToRunLast);
functionToRunFirst();
```

This can be handy with the DOM.  Sometimes you change it, but the changes don't parse or render immediately.  At the end of the run loop, the browser catches up and parses and renders the DOM, then the next run loop starts and can interact with the newly rendered DOM.

*(Exactly what scenarios cause this delayed DOM parse, I'm not sure, but I've noticed it in my own projects in the past.)*

---

It is *NOT* a replacement for DOM ready.  The next run loop may happen *before* DOM ready ever fires, don't confuse these concepts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the DOM will be updated immediately but the rendering (and hence things like sizing and positioning) generally won't happen until after the browser gets control back; this is why you often need a `defer` (or the equivalent `setTimeout`) when you want to bind Google Maps to something that you just added: the map wants to know how big things are but that information isn't available until the browser gets a chance to compute it.

Comment: Thanks Alex that helps a lot!

Comment: how does _.defer() compare to setTimeout(fn, 0) ??

Comment: @whiteb0x It's basically the same thing.  Checkout out the [underscore source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-70) and you'll see that `defer` call's `delay` with a time of `1`, and `delay` calls `setTimeout`.

Comment: Your answer is correct, although what you're calling "loops" is technically called "messages." The messages are added to a queue. The event loop processes each of the messages, one at a time. When you call setTimeout, it puts the callback at the end of the queue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney The link to EventLoop on MDN was very helpful.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a difference/reason underscore sets the timeout to 1, rather than 0?

Comment: @mAAdhaTTah discussion on that is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341803/difference-between-settimeoutfn-0-and-settimeoutfn-1