# Is `setTimeout(func, 0)` and `setTimeout(func, 1)` considered the same?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, settimeout

Here are some simple Javascript code using `setTimeout`:

```js
function setTimeouts() {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(2); }, 2);
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(1); }, 1);
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(0); }, 0);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeouts();
}
```

When I run it on Chrome or Node.js, the results are similar:

```
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

You can see all tasks with timeout `0` and `1` are before timeout `2`, which is what I expected.

But the `0` and `1` are mixed with each other, seems like they have the same timeout. What I expected is all `0` before `1`.

How to understand this?

Comment: Is this NodeJS or Google Chrome? Both have different timer implementations that are specified differently and in other places.

Comment: @Freewind:Any specific reasons why you expected `0` before `1`?

Comment: @Freewind: This is a wonderful talk on the event loop in node which may answer your question..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: I add an answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37961816/342235

Answer (score 0):

Actually, setTimeout's second parameters has minimum value limitation. For firefox the value is 4ms. If the passed value is less than minimum value, minimum will be used.

Regarding your question, I think this article is helpful: http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth

Comment: Please run <http://jsbin.com/cefowipadi/edit?html,js,console,output> on firefox. The tasks with smaller timeout are executed first, even if they `<= 4`